# (node:2072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined Discord js | Mongoose | MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a simple welcome message on discord js with an event handler. It would work if I do it on the main file, but it does not work when I try it here. Code Below:

```
const profileModel = require('../../database/models/profileSchema');
let WelcomeSchema = require(`../../database/models/welcomeSchema`)
const Discord = require(`discord.js`)
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`)

module.exports = (client, member, GuildMember) => {
 WelcomeSchema.findOne({ guildID: member.guild.id}, async (err, data, user) => {

    
    console.log(member.guild.id)
    if(!data) return;
    const channel = await client.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === `${data.WelcomeChannel}`)
    channel.send(`Welcome ${member}, ${data.WelcomeMsg}`)
  

})
}
```

```
Below Is My Event Handler (keep in mind the code above had the file name of, guildMemberAdd)
```

```
fs.readdirSync(`./events`).forEach(dirs => {
    const events = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith(`.js`))
    for (const file of events) {
        console.log(`Loading discord.js event ${file}`);
        const event = require(`./events/${dirs}/${file}`);
        client.on(file.split(".")[0], event.bind(null, client));
    }
});
```

Below Is The Full Error

```
(node:2072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at E:\Software\Github Repository shit\EA-BOT\events\Other\guildMemberAdd.js:15:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:2072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2072) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

```
Below Is Line 15 (where the error was at)
```

```
(line 14) const channel = await client.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === `${data.WelcomeChannel}`)
 (line 15)   channel.send(`Welcome ${member}, ${data.WelcomeMsg}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory. `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` you are attempting to invoke `.send()` method of something undefined - meaning `channel` is undefined. If we take a look at line 14, the logical explanation is that there is no channel, for which

```
x.id === `${data.WelcomeChannel}`
```

is true.
The line `if (!data) return;` for your purposes is not specific enough. It appears `data` exists, but either `data.WelcomeChannel` does not, or IDs don't much.

Try to use line `if (!data.WelcomeChannel) return;` and see if this exits your code. Then double-check `data.WelcomeChannel` is a correct channel id (and if it's actually an `id`, not channel `object`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
const channel = await client.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === `${data.WelcomeChannel}`)
```

to get your Discord.channel, try doing this:

```
const channel = await client.channels.cache.get(data.WelcomeChannel)
```

*Note: I can't test the fix myself because I'm currently in school, but this may fix your issue.*